# How do I denote a triangle?

Tags: notation, triangles, convention

[image]

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle),

> A triangle with vertices A, B, and C is denoted $\triangle ABC$.

Can I call the above triangle $\triangle ACB$ or $\triangle BAC$ or so on?

Comment: The convention expresses the order of the vertex.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  What does the order of the vertex mean? Do I have to maintain alphabetical order?

Comment: The convention makes it slightly easier to find the triangle on a crowded diagram.  Start leftmost  and circle around counterclockwise.

Comment: The order only matters if you talk about similar/congruent triangles, or some ordering is implied. Something like "In $\triangle BCA$ the angle bisectors intersect the opposite sides at $P$, $Q$, $R$".

Comment: With a triangle, it's impossible to get the "order of the vert[ices]" wrong; each of $ABC$, $BCA$, $CAB$, $ACB$, $BAC$, $CBA$ —ie, *every possible* order— represents a path around the figure. (W/quadrilaterals & beyond, you can't scramble letters willy-nilly.) That said, while $\triangle ABC$, $\triangle BCA$, etc, are all acceptable names for the triangle, it can be a courtesy to the reader to use the "least weird" option (unless you have reason to do otherwise), which may be alphabetical. ("Reasons" include matching the order of a similar triangle, listing an "important" vertex first, etc.)

Comment: The order of the letter sort of induces an orientation for the triangle. ABC, can be thought of as counter clock wise, BAC as clockwise etc. If you ignore this, then there is not much different

Comment: Yes and yes to Blue's comment.